# jQuery target a specific div with another var

Tags: php, jquery, html

So, I have the following php and js markup:

```
<div class="top" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
  <div class="middle">
    Click
  </div>
  <div class="info"> <!--Note that I am targeting a child div -->
     <div class="name">
       Steve
     </div> 
  </div>     
</div>
```

Then for my js:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.middle', function(e) {
  var my_id= jQuery(this).parent('.top').data("id");
});
```

At this point, when the `middle` div is clicked, the js var `my_id` is equal to the `data_id` of its top parent div (with `.top`).

Now, I want to save another div as below (simple html).

```
var my_name = $('.name').html();
```

How do I target the specific `.name` class within the specific `data-id' div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `.siblings()` method to select all the sibling elements of `.middle`, and then use `.find()` to find any descendant `.name` elements:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.middle', function(e) {
  var my_id= jQuery(this).parent('.top').data("id");
  var my_name = jQuery(this).siblings().find('.name').html();
});
```

Comment: Would this `siblings` work anything within the `.top` div container? For example, I have multilevel div containers within the `.top` div and I need to target these multilevel divs within this top.

Comment: @steveKim Yes, it will select them if they are siblings. In other words, it will select the `.name` element if it appears before/after the `.middle` element (only if it is a sibling at the same level though of course).

Comment: When you say sibling, would the multilevel div (ie, child divs) also be applied to this ? Thank you for the reply

Comment: @steveKim No. Siblings are elements at the same level. If the `.name`/`.middle` elements are at different levels, it wouldn't select them. I just updated my answer, you would need to chain `.find()` after `.siblings()` like: `$('.middle').siblings().find('.name')`.

Comment: Perfect. learning something new today! =) Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Use the parent and find methods.

```
var current;
$(document).on( 'click', '.middle', function(e) {
  var my_id= $(this).parent('.top').data("id");
  current = $(this).parent().find('.name');
  console.log($(current).html());
});
```

Edit: John Crozier's answer is more complete. Beat me to it :)